# Restricted premissions for passphrases using cryptsetup

Tags: linux, encryption, permissions, luks

Hello Stack community,

when using cryptsetup (in Ubuntu console), is it possible to restrict the creation of new passphrases exclusively to the cases when the passphrase in the slot 0 is used?

What I am aiming for is: 'admin' gets the password created at encryption (so, slot 0), 'user' get the subsequently created passwords. What I want to avoid is that users can create additional passwords or delete any.

From what I found via Google it doesn't look like this, but I wanted to hear a definite 'no' before I give up. Any advice about tools, which can be used with cryptsetup to enable the above functionality is greatly appreciated!